# Payum - symfony2 bundle not redirecting me to paypal on paypal express checkout

Tags: symfony, payum

I have been trying all day to setup the payum bundle but it seems as if there are parts missing in the install tutorial of this bundle.

I have the form but when i click the button "Pay" it is not redirecting me to paypal

I am using the code as described here :
http://sandbox.payum.forma-dev.com/paypal/express-checkout/repare_simple_purchase_and_doctrine

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In most cases it is wrong paypal credentials, double check you use right. Also you could check for errors in the model table. There is l_errorxxx fields. They might contain something interesting.