# PayumBundle Security header is not valid

Tags: php, symfony, payum

I configure PayumBundle in symfony2 but not work :)

im not redirected to paypal site.

i get error - 'error', 'Payment failed' where i can find some informations ?

Update 1

i foud error : in var_dump($status)

'L_SHORTMESSAGE0' => string 'Security error' (length=14)
  'L_LONGMESSAGE0' => string 'Security header is not valid' (length=28)

when i turn off in config sandbox im redirected to paypal but i dont have filled amount , payment name - how to configure it ?

i configure it from this example http://payum.forma-dev.com/documentation/0.8/PayumBundle/simple_purchase_examples/paypal_express_checkout

config:

```
payum:
    security:
        token_storage:
            ed\partnerBundle\Entity\PayumSecurityToken:
                doctrine:
                    driver: orm
    contexts:
        frei_payment:
            paypal_express_checkout_nvp:
              api:
                  options:
                      username:  'myusername'
                      password:  'mypass'
                      signature: 'mysing'
                      sandbox: true
            storages:
                ed\partnerBundle\Entity\PaymentDetails:
                    doctrine:
                        driver: orm
```

routing :

```
payment_start:
    pattern:  /payment
    defaults: { _controller: edpartnerBundle:Payment:preparePaypalExpressCheckoutPayment }

edpartner_payment_done:
    pattern:  /payment/done
    defaults: { _controller: edpartnerBundle:Payment:done }
```

actions in Payment Controller:

```
  public function doneAction(){

        $request = $this->getRequest();

        $token = $this->get('payum.security.http_request_verifier')->verify($request);

        $payment = $this->get('payum')->getPayment($token->getPaymentName());

        $status = new BinaryMaskStatusRequest($token);
        $payment->execute($status);

        if ($status->isSuccess()) {
            $this->getUser()->addCredits(100);
            $this->getRequest()->getSession()->getFlashBag()->set(
                'notice',
                'Payment success. Credits were added'
            );
        } else if ($status->isPending()) {
            $this->getRequest()->getSession()->getFlashBag()->set(
                'notice',
                'Payment is still pending. Credits were not added'
            );
        } else {
            $this->getRequest()->getSession()->getFlashBag()->set('error', 'Payment failed');
        }

        return $this->redirect('homepage');



    }

    /**
     */
    public function preparePaypalExpressCheckoutPaymentAction(){

        $paymentName = 'my_payment';

        $storage = $this->get('payum')->getStorageForClass(
            'ed\partnerBundle\Entity\PaymentDetails',
            $paymentName
        );

        /** @var \ed\partnerBundle\Entity\PaymentDetails $paymentDetails */
        $paymentDetails = $storage->createModel();
        $paymentDetails['PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE'] = 'USD';
        $paymentDetails['PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT'] = 1.23;
        $storage->updateModel($paymentDetails);

        $captureToken = $this->get('payum.security.token_factory')->createCaptureToken(
            $paymentName,
            $paymentDetails,
            'edpartner_payment_done' // the route to redirect after capture;
        );

        $paymentDetails['INVNUM'] = $paymentDetails->getId();
        $paymentDetails['RETURNURL'] = $captureToken->getTargetUrl();
        $paymentDetails['CANCELURL'] = $captureToken->getTargetUrl();
        $storage->updateModel($paymentDetails);


        return $this->redirect($captureToken->getTargetUrl());



    }
```

i go to /payment url in browser and im redirected to homepage i see new records in database - but i dont make any payment - why im not redirected to paypal for payment ?

Answer (score 2):

Ok in found error - this is sandbox error - normal api key - dont allow sandbox mode - 
a pity that it is not described in bundle install manual - and a the bundle dont throw any exception -  simple redirect without info...

Comment: That was asked several times here. Actually payum saves all the information to your details model. You would have to find there L_ERRORLONG0 (something like this) fields with a text "Security header invalid".

Comment: Check details whenever you have some troubles. It has to contain all the details payum can fetch from a gateway.

Comment: You may check this question for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18548701/payum-symfony2-bundle-not-redirecting-me-to-paypal-on-paypal-express-checkout